# Rebus saga consistency

Tags: c#, rebus, rebus-rabbitmq

I'm facing a weird situation were my sagas ***sometimes*** just stop invoking next steps while no errors are written to the logs. so for example consider this (pseudo)code:

```
public async Task Handle(Step1 step1)
{
  //... do something
  await _bus.Send(new Step2 { Id = step1.Id });
}

public async Task Handle(Step2 step2)
{
  //... do something else
  // go to next step      
}
```

In this case `step1` is handled fine but there are just no signs of `Handle(Step2 step2)` ever being invoked with the saga data just sitting in the SQL table with `revision` field being equal to `1` and no messages in main or error queues of the RabbitMq. Is at-least-once delivery guarantee applicable here? Any suggestions of how this is possible or which debug information I could add?
I'm using MySQL persistence and RabbitMq transport with this config:

```
services.AddRebus(configure => configure
    .Logging(l => l.MicrosoftExtensionsLogging(loggerFactory))
    .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq(rabbitMqConnection, "rebusqueue"))
    .Sagas(s => 
          {
              s.StoreInMySql(dbConnection, "Rebus_Saga_Data", "Rebus_Saga_Data_Index");
              s.EnforceExclusiveAccess();
          })
     .Timeouts(t => t.StoreInMySql(dbConnection, "Rebus_Saga_Timeouts"))
     .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().MapAssemblyOf<MessageBase>("rebusqueue")));
```

Comment: Could something else by any chance be consuming messages from the queue "rebusqueue"?

Comment: @mookid8000 I can't think of any. Do I understand it correctly that the message is reported as "processed" to rabbitmq only after the `Handle` method completed invocation without exceptions? So I can be sure that `await _bus.Send(new Step2 { Id = step1.Id })` from my question was successfully invoked, the `Step2` message was successfully persisted in RabbitMq and only after that the `Step1` message was marked as complete and removed from RabbitMq?

Comment: Rebus ACKs the message with RabbitMQ as the _very last thing_ after having handled it. The order is like this: 1) fetch saga matching the incoming message, 2) invoke your handler code, 3) update saga data in database, 4) send outgoing messages, 5) ACK the message

Comment: @mookid8000 ok thanks, I see, is there an easy way to configure logging to see  all sent/received/seen/failed etc messages (maybe just IDs or full bodies serialized to JSON)?

Comment: not really, no - if you're interested, I can debug your problem if you can reproduce it and post the code in a repository somewhere

Comment: @mookid8000 the issue is that it's flaky and I can't see a pattern here. I also see sometimes my sagas are started several times for the same message ID, my logic handles those but still curious why it happens - I don't have any retries when doing `await _bus.Send(..)`. Anyway I added manual logging around each `_bus` call and will continue monitoring, thanks for your replies I'll post my results if I manage to figure out the issue